# Stored procedure execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I have written a stored procedure to be called from `sqlcmd` (batch file). This is the code - for some reason it is not executing.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P FDate=Enter From Date: 
SET /P TDate=Enter To Date: 
ECHO sqlcmd -E -Q "dbo.SavingsAccountsAllDetail @FDate=N'%Param1%', @TDate=N'%Param2%'" -S OMNIDB-UAT -d HNBG_LOAN_TEST -o C:\SavingsAccountsAllDetailRepo.txt
SET Param1=
SET Param2=
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `EXEC` before procedure's name:

```
sqlcmd -E -Q "exec dbo.SavingsAccountsAllDetail @FDate=N'%Param1%', @TDate=N'%Param2%'" -S OMNIDB-UAT -d HNBG_LOAN_TEST -o C:\SavingsAccountsAllDetailRepo.txt
```

You can also try to passparameters via the `/v` argument. More datais [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx)

```
sqlcmd -E -Q "exec dbo.SavingsAccountsAllDetail @FDate=N'$(Param1)', @TDate=N'$(Param2)'" /v Param1=%Param1% Param2=%Param2%  -S OMNIDB-UAT -d HNBG_LOAN_TEST -o C:\SavingsAccountsAllDetailRepo.txt
```

Comment: There are no errors, it just prompts to enter the from and to dates and session is closing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89162/discussion-between-megatron-and-dee-dee).